# Yii2 add column from join table without asArray method

Tags: php, join, yii2

I was trying to get in my select result column from joined table. My query looks like this:

```
$query = MediaLibrary::find()->select([
  'media_library.*',
  'category_name'   =>'ctg.name',
  'category_id'     =>'ctg.id',
  'entity_name'     =>'ent.name',
  'entity_id'       =>'ent.id',
  'category_alias'  =>'ctg.alias',
])->joinWith([
  'mediaLibraryCategory' => function ($q) {
    $q->from(MediaLibraryCategory::tableName().' ctg');
  },
  'mediaLibraryEntity' => function ($q) {
    $q->from(MediaLibraryEntity::tableName().' ent');
  }
])->asArray();
```

It works, okey. But the problem is that I don't want to get that arrays of data from another tables (asArray() method). But if I delete that method - columns from another tables are gone.

What I am doing wrong? Is there way to add columns without asArray() method?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `joinWith()` method without second param `$eagerLoading`. If the `$eagerLoading` parameter is true, the method will also perform eager loading for the specified relations, which is equivalent to calling with() using the specified relations. To solve your issue, add second param `false` to your `joinWith()` function.

More in [Yii2 ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail)

Comment: correct! I was about to write the same. you beat me to it

Comment: yes, now I see - I should leave asArray() and add false parameter. Now it works, thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @KatyaMakeeva, if this answer satisfy you, please select it as the correct answer. Also, please upvote it if you want to show some gratitude.